# How to resolve: warning: not protecting local variables: variable length buffer

Tags: gcc

when building my project, the following warning is generated:

**warning: not protecting local variables: variable length buffer**

i have enabled the stack protector and already specified the size however this is still occurring.

**-fstack-protector-all -Wall -Wstack-protector --param ssp-buffer-size=2**

can you suggest a way to resolve the warning without actually turning off the warning flags? thanks

Comment: i do beleive it would be helpfull to see WHICH piece of code actually produces the wartning

Comment: actually i am not allowed to disclose the code. however the warning points to the beginning of several functions and not the exact part within the function. :(

Comment: I'd say the compiler looks for space allocated on the stack, and at some point it figures out that there is some object that is reserved on the stack, but the length of the object can not be determined by the compiler.